# How to use group by query here

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

```
Id  BatchName      TblName           SubBatchName     Status
1   12032014    Tbl_12032014_raw2_1  raw2           Complete    
2   12032014    Tbl_12032014_raw2_2  raw2           Complete    
3   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw3_1  raw3           Complete        
4   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw3_2  raw3           Complete        
5   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw4_1  raw4           Complete        
6   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw4_2  raw4           Complete        
7   12062014    Tbl_12062014_raw5_1  raw5           Complete    
8   12062014    Tbl_12062014_raw5_2  raw5           Complete
9   12062014    Tbl_12062014_raw5_3  raw5           InComplete
```

i want output like below

```
BatchName                                                                                 
--------------------
12032014  
12182014
```

If all rows of batchname are having status complete then and then only BatchName Get select

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all `BatchName` where all statuses are `Complete`?

Instead of a `Group By` you could also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.BatchName 
FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE t1.Status = 'Complete'
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
                WHERE  t1.BatchName = t2.BatchName 
                 AND   ISNULL(t2.Status,'') <> 'Complete')
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecc8b/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Group by the batch and takle only those having no status other than `Complete`

```
select batchname
from your_table
group by batchname
having sum(case when status <> 'Complete' or status is null
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) = 0
```

Comment: But this also shows batches where the status is NULL. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbc2f/1/0